# How to uninstall Igniton Gazebo 6

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ubuntu, gazebo-9, gazebo-ignition

I have install ros2 `humble` & `iron` on ubuntu `22.04`.I need an older version of Gazebo `Gazebo6` for some simulation now I want to uninstall `Igniton Gazebo 6`. I am not able to do with `sudo apt remove` command

Comment: Please update this question with specific details about why you are unable to use the `sudo apt remove` command. In its current form, your question cannot be answered, because there is not enough information here.